# Why it is raised? Error: Minified Redux error #12;

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

Why do I get this:

> Error: Minified Redux error #12;

Added Next.js React supprt based on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIqvxQnPOCM

```js
//slices/User.ts

import { Action, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { GetUserOut } from "../tikexModule/Types";

const initialState: GetUserOut = undefined;

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action: PayloadAction<GetUserOut | undefined>) {
      state = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

```js
//store.ts

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./slices/User";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { user: userReducer },
});
```

```js
//pages/_app.js

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialState` is not allowed to be `undefined` as a Redux reducer may never return `undefined`. Try `null` instead.